# PHP OpenSSL is missing during composer installation on Windows

Tags: composer-php

I have a LAMP server Denwer installed on Windows 7. When I try to install composer, it stops with "The openssl extension is missing... If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl" message.
Despite that I OpenSSL extension already enabled, I checked that by running this command:

```
> php -i | find "OpenSSL"
OpenSSL support => enabled
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should have openssl extension enabled inside php.ini. `php -m` and search for `openssl`

Comment: Thankyou, but I already enabled openssl in my php.ini and "php -m" show "openssl" among others.

Comment: You should check which php.ini are you using. From what I remember since I was running Windows, Wamp stores php.ini in different locations. There is one in Apache directory, other in Windows directory and other in php directory. To check if this is the issue, run composer like (assumes that php.ini is in D:\Wamp\Apache directory): `php -c D:\Wamp\Apache\php composer.phar install`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using not WAMP. But when I tried install composer with command line `php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php` it was successfull. So the problem occur only when I try to install with Composer-Setup.exe, so it use another php.ini, but I don't know which.

Comment: Denver **is** a Wamp stack (You said LAMP in the question, but that is for linux). Specify a path to a known good php.ini when you run php from command line (ie: *php -c <D:\path\to\good\php.ini> composer.phar install*) and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: I already installed composer with command line (`php composer.phar install` - without specifing php.ini works), but I wnat use composer from the command line without downloading it every time. Or I missed something?